# Does OpenGLES-2 supports iPod Touch 3G?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, ipod, info.plist

We developing several apps/games on iOS platform. We need to have minimal support of opengles-2.

We have to configure at info.plist, Required Device Capabilities => opengles-2 => YES.

Now within this config, will iPod Touch 3G device be capable to install our game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Apple Developer Library it says that the third generation of iPod Touch supports OpenGL ES 2.0.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html